# Multiple subscriber queue allocation using the same callback

Tags: ros, multiple, queue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating multiple subscribers using the same callback function as in [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/51706/using-a-callback-for-multiple-subscribers-emulating-physical-outputs/), the code is [here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/How-to-identify-the-subscriber-or-the-topic-name-related-to-a-callback-td2391327.html).

Basically is this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i<topics.size(); i++ )  
    sub[i] = n_.subscribe( topics[i], queue_size, &MyClass::callback, this );
```

In this case to whom is assigned `queue_size`? How does it work?

I would like to think that `queue_size` is assigned to the subscriber `sub[i]` and that it doesn't matter that all the subscribers use the same callback. I mean:

Is the `queue_size` independent of the callback function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229425/multiple-subscriber-queue-allocation-using-the-same-callback/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `queue_size` is specific to each subscriber. It only controls the 'number of incoming messages to queue up for processing (messages in excess of this queue capacity will be discarded).' (http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html).

You can have multiple subscribers using the same callback function but with different queue sizes.

e.g sub1 and sub2 both use myCallBack() and subscribe to "/mytopic1" and "/mytopic2" respectively, sub1 has queue_size=1, sub2 has queue_size=10

If I publish 15 identical messages "instantaneously" on both topics (faster than the time it takes to complete myCallBack()), you should see 2 calls to myCallBack() corresponding to sub1 for messages 1 (assuming sub1's callback is processed first) and 15, and 10 calls to myCallBack() corresponding to sub2 for messages 6-15.

Also remember that by default, all the callbacks within a node are invoked from a single global callback queue. You can assign separate callback queues for each of your subscribers if that is what you are looking for, but it takes a bit more work (http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3